# Play or playing (a musical instrument)

Tags: word-choice

When comparing two musical instruments to see which one is easier to play, is it correct to say that we compare them by "ease of play" or "ease of playing"? Which one would be best?

And in order to express the way a musician plays (in the physical sense, not referring to a performance), would we talk about "musician's play", "musician's playing", or something else?

Comment: For example: We use pressure sensors to analyse the musician's play(ing). When choosing a new instrument, musicians value ease of play(ing) over price.

Comment: Thanks! The ideas that I'm trying to express in the two sentences are different. From your answer, I understand that 'ease of playing' would be better  for the second sentence, as it is similar to 'effort of playing'. 

In the first sentence the idea is not that we use the sensors to analyse how hard it is to play, but how she or he physically plays the instrument

Comment: Maybe my question was confusing, I was actually asking about two different things I need to express. The 'ease of playing' part is clear. Regarding the 'musician's play(ing)', the background of the question is that I want to compare how an instrument is played by a musician and by a machine (long story...), so the idea is to express the 'way to play' rather than the 'effort to play'. Could you please copy your 'ease of playing' example as an answer (rather than a comment) so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence, it may be the 'effort of playing the instrument' rather than playing. You need to ask musicians what they expect, as they are your audience.

You are saying that you study how hard the musician works physically to play instrument A over B, like electric guitars take less pressure to play than acoustic guitars do. That's **ease of playing**, not play.

A violin bow is said to have a lot of *play* when it is not tightened very much: *Movement or space for movement, as of mechanical parts.* - [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/play)